# Can I allow Google Analytics tracking on a single page/Domain for multipule users?

Tags: google-analytics

So I have a saas site. It uses a single domain (we will call it domain.com) and a single page (we will use index.php). However, based on the query string, it loads content for a specific user. So example:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?u=12345 Loads content for John Doe

http://domain.com/index.php?u=98765 Loads content for Jane Doe
```

These two users have no relation to one another. However, both want to track traffic to their specific pages using their own Google Analytics code.

So based on the query string, it would pull the Analytics code for each user into the page dynamically.

I don't want to setup a single Google Analytics account and give access to each user.

Is there a way to allow each user to setup their own Google Analytics account then in their user interface, allow them to put their own tracking code and have it only report to them traffic for their specific query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem to have multiple Google Analytics accounts/web property IDs for a single domain, but there's a few things you might want to consider:

- Whether someone might visit multiple users pages. By default, Google Analytics uses a cookie at the root level (/), so if someone visits pages with different analytics accounts, there could be mixing of data. You could use `_setCookiePath` to keep the user's data separate. See [_setCookiePath](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCookiePath)
- How many users are you going to have and who creates the analytics profiles? Google Analytics has hard limits to the number of profiles on an analytics account -- 50 profiles, though it can be bumped to 100. There's also a limit as to how many accounts a single Google user can create. You might be better off having your users create their own Google Analytics accounts/profiles and set their web property ID `UA-XXXXX-X` in the configuration.
- Do you want to have some kind of roll-up tracking that tracks across all the sites? In that case, you can add code to track to a second web property ID.

Here's sample code that tracks both the whole site, where `XXXXX-X` is the web property ID used for the entire site, and `YYYYY-Y` is the individual users ID that you substitute in. Note that the individual users cookie path is set to their web property ID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['b._setCookiePath', '/UA-YYYYY-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-YYYYY-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the cookie path have to be a real path? Or can I set that to a UUID I have for each user?

Comment: Good question -- I thought the _setCookiePath argument could be an arbitrary string, but I just ran a test in Chrome and it looks like it has to be a real path. When I used a path like '/UA-12345-1', it didn't save any cookies.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the customizations for the user (via the query string), also load their analytics javascript snippet.

Comment: But will google allow multiple people to create accounts for the same domain name?